# xetex - myriad pro - want "bold" but not "bold condensed" font

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

Situation: I've got Myriad Pro included in xetex via:

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Myriad Pro}
```

But when I use

```
\textbf{this is a test}
```

and see the result in Acrobat, I can see that I've gotten "MyriadPro-BoldCond" rather than only "MyriadPro-Bold". I need a suggestions on how to change the behaviour so that I get "bold", not bold condensed.

Comment: (EDIT: thought it was a `LuaTeX` question first time.) What does your `.log` file say?  A minimal document yields for me:  `Font family 'MyriadPro(0)' created for font 'Myriad Pro' with options`....

Comment: Out of curiosity: Do you happen to run MacTeX? The reason I ask is that I've encountered similar problems (actually, running LuaLaTeX rather than XeLaTeX) when trying to load a font such as `Garamond Premier Pro` via a `\setmainfont` directive; the italics font that is loaded if no explicit `ItalicFont = ...` is provided turns out to be `Garamond Premier Pro Semibold Italic` rather than `Garamond Premier Pro Italic`... I have no idea if MacTeX or MacOSX is the culprit, or how long this has been going on.

Comment: @Mico, no, I am running MikTeX with Windows underneath, but as you say, I have the suspicion that the underlying system has to do something with it;

Comment: @jon,
`. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'MyriadPro(0)' created for font 'Myriad Pro' with options
. [Mapping=tex-text].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
. 
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Myriad Pro/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. 
. * 'bold' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Myriad Pro/B/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. 
. * 'italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Myriad Pro/I/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"
. 
. * 'bold italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"Myriad Pro/BI/ICU:script=latn;language=DFLT;mapping=tex-text;"`

Comment: `\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box41
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 29.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 29.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following setup should ensure the use of the desired bold fontface:

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, % better, set "Ligatures = TeX",
             BoldFont={Myriad Pro Bold}] % you may also want to consider "Myriad Pro Semibold"
       {Myriad Pro}
```